# Based on Virgil Dobjanschi Android Rest Client using AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter for Rest Client

Tags: android

I wanted to write a Android Rest Client for my Application using AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter, My rest server don't need Authuntication. My questions are.

1. Is AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter is used only for Authentication application ?
2. if not how to use it as a normal Rest Client.
3. Can i get a good sample code for it?